# Can ID Verification data (such as name, address, etc. that was extracted from the submitted ID image) be passed to an integrated system?

Tags: docusignapi

Can ID Verification data (such as name, address, etc. that was extracted from the submitted ID image) be passed to an integrated system? I want to be able to use DocuSign data that was extracted during the DocuSign ID Verification process to perform some additional downstream processes in a different system that integrates with DocuSign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no it cannot because DocuSign uses a third party vendor to do that and it's not DocuSign that is doing the validation.

Comment: Thanks, Inbar. Do you know who the 3rd party vendor is that DocuSign uses for the validation? I was hoping to be able to use extracted information rather than needing to OCR/ICR the ID image.

Comment: LexisNexis (read about it here - https://www.docusign.com/partner/docusign-id-check-powered-by-lexisnexis-risk-solutions)

Comment: This is for ID Check. Do they use the same vendor for ID Verify? These are two different features.

Comment: oops, sorry, you're right, I gave you the info for KB search not IDV.

Comment: I can't answer who is the vendor, there are different vendors in different countries and regions and they can change at any time. Sorry about the confusion

Comment: Gotcha. No prob! Thanks for all the info. This was helpful.

Comment: Jacob, if you don't mind marking this as answered. thanks.